# SQL - Get difference of two sums

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the difference of two sums using this:

```
SELECT ((SELECT SUM(`amount`)
         WHERE `reward_user_id` = 89
         FROM `plugin_reward_aggregated`)
        -
        (SELECT SUM(`amount`)
         WHERE `download_date` >= CURDATE ()
         FROM `plugin_reward_aggregated`));
```

but it shows an error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `reward_user_id` = 89
FROM `plugin_reward_aggregated`)
...' at line 2

Comment: The error message tells you all. Why did you post this?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `reward_user_id` = 89
         FROM `plugin_reward_aggregated`)
     ...' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

You have `SELECT SELECT` in there, that's invalid syntax. It helps to format your query nicely instead of letting it just be one unreadably long line:

```sql
SELECT ((SELECT SUM(`amount`)
         WHERE `reward_user_id` = 89
         FROM `plugin_reward_aggregated`)
        -
        (SELECT SELECT SUM(`amount`)
         WHERE `download_date` >= CURDATE ()
         FROM `plugin_reward_aggregated`));
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `reward_user_id` = 89
         FROM `plugin_reward_aggregated`)
     ...' at line 2

Comment: oh, right, `FROM` also needs to come before `WHERE`. This is really basic stuff, have you considered going through an SQL tutorial?